# Elasticsearch update documents without retrieving them

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to update documents something similar to UpdateByQuery, but in bulks and without getting them.
According to the documentation we are unable to set a size for UpdateByQuery requests.

I.e Update 5 documents at a time and not all at once.

One solution  that seems obvious is to GET 5 documents, and then UPDATE them.
I'm trying to come up with a way where I dont have to do a GET request for every update.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the batch size on `UpdateByQueryRequest` with `setBatchSize` as in this page from the docs.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-update-by-query.html

Now that's based on the latest version of the Java client. If you are using a different client or version, it may not be present. Hope that helps.

Comment: For every update I make, I need to do another request somewhere else before I update the next batch.
Also I'm using the javascript client.